# grpc WriteAsync locking up server

Tags: c#, grpc

Grpc.Core 2.38.0

I have a collection of applications participating in inter process communication using grpc streaming.  From time to time we've noticed a lockup and memory exhaustion (due to the lockup) in the server processes being unable to finish a call to `IAsyncStreamWriter.WriteAsync(...)`

Recent changes to grpc (.net) have changed the `WriteAsync` API to accept a `CancellationToken`, however this is not available in the `Grpc.Core` package.

Answer (score 1):

A misconfigured grpc client accepting a stream can cause a deadlock.  If a client *does not* dispose of the `AsyncServerStreamingCall` during error handling, the deadlock will occur on the server.

Example:

```
async Task ClientStreamingThread()
{
    while (...)
    {
        var theStream = grpcService.SomeStream(new());
        try
        {
            while (await theStream.ResponseStream.MoveNext(shutdownToken.Token))
            {
                var theData = theStream.ResponseStream.Current;
            }
        }
        catch (RpcException)
        {
            // if an exception occurs, start over, reopen the stream
        }
    }
}
```

The example above contains the misbehaving client.  If an `RpcException` occurs, we'll return to the start of the while loop and open another stream **without** cleaning up the previous.  This causes the deadlock.

"Fix" the client code by disposing of the previous stream like the following:

```
async Task ClientStreamingThread()
{
    while (...)
    {
        // important.  dispose of theStream if it goes out of scope
        using var theStream = grpcService.SomeStream(new());
        try
        {
            while (await theStream.ResponseStream.MoveNext(shutdownToken.Token))
            {
                var theData = theStream.ResponseStream.Current;
            }
        }
        catch (RpcException)
        {
            // if an exception occurs, start over, reopen the stream
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you believe this is a grpc bug, feel free to file a github issue. But note that we'd need a better example, since from your snippets it isn't really clear whether this is a grpc bug or not (a minimal ready-to-run reproduction as a github repository would be ideal).